# Pass array to string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a function correctly to work with tags, however when saving in the database, the data is represented as an array, and I would like it to be represented as a string, how can I solve this?

```
  private tags: string[] = [];

private addTagToProduct($event): void {
    this.tags.push($event.target.value);
    $event.target.value = "";
  }

  private deleteTagFromProduct(tag: string): void {
    this.tags = this.tags.filter((a) => a !== tag);
  }
```

**SERVER**

```
string tags;

public string Tags { get => tags; set => tags = value; }

  public Rep CreateProduct(SqlConnection conn, Product products)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaction;
            conn.Open();
            transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO[Products](Tags)" +
                            " Values (@TagS)";
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tags", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Tags;
                        cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        transaction.Commit();          
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();                
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Dalorzo SQL Server

Comment: @maccettura I believe this is typescript

Comment: @Harry can you show us your serve side code where the information is saved?

Comment: @Dalorzo 
That's enough?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to send a string to the server, just call:

```
this.tags.map((input) => "'" + input + "'").join(",")
```

and send it to your server. However, you will need to make sure that there is no SQL injection, so I would advise you to use an array and generate your insertion accordingly.

Comment: The down-vote on this answer seems to mean that it should be improved or removed, however, I do not find the comment which would explain why it's wrong.

Comment: really I don't understand the downvote. NOTE: it's not necessary enclosed the values of the array between quotes, just `.join(',') make the trick

Comment: @Eliseo that's a good point. I considered that possibility, but decided to do a .map() call instead of adding quotes at the start and the end of the expression (to handle the very first and very last quote). I considered the code this way to be more organized, but one can argue for getting rid of the call to map, use the join as you described. If one presents that position, I can understand his/her point as well.

Comment: is you make `[0,1,2,3].join(',')` return `"0,1,2,3"`

Comment: @Eliseo you are right about that, sorry, was really tired when I reacted to it initially.